# Using Javascript in android WebView to call a function

Tags: javascript, android, webview

**Background:-**

I am trying to call a `@JavascriptInterface` annotated method `processVideo()` form the `loadUrl()` of webview to get callback when someone click on any video on the webpage.

The following is my approach and it's working perfectly

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view_facebook);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Downloader");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function prepareVideo() { "
                    + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                    + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                    + "{"
                    + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                    + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                    + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                    + "console.log(i);"
                    + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                    + "el[i].addEventListener('click',function(){Downloader.processVideo(jsonData['src'],jsonData['videoID']);});"
                    + "}" + "}" + "})()");
       }
    });


    webView.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com");


}

@JavascriptInterface
public void processVideo(final String vidData, final String vidID) {


    try {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download Failed: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}}
```

**Now The Problem:-**

But as i load custom javascript function in `loadUrl()`, i lost the ability to play video on click.
i think it will happen as i intercepted and load my custom code

So what i want to achieve is when any user click on video, then the video should play and also i get the callback that i wanted at first place

**What i have tried so far:-**

to play the video on click, i used

```
addEventListener('click',function(){ 
var video = document.getElementById(jsonData['videoID']); 
video.play(); }
```

This one is working perfectly to play the video.

but when i use this solution with my callback like following

```
 addEventListener('click',function(){ 
    Downloader.processVideo(jsonData['src'],jsonData['videoID']);
    var video = document.getElementById(jsonData['videoID']); 
    video.play(); }
```

then I am not able to get callback in my `processVideo()`.

If i use them individually, both functionality (callback and play video) working perfectly inside `addEventListener()`, but not working together.

Answer (score 0):

This code line: `var video = document.getElementById('jsonData['videoID']')` throws an error because you used more than two `'`s in one argument.

Try replacing by `var video = document.getElementById(jsonData['videoID'])`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this but now i'm not able to play the video on click, yes i'm getting the callback now. but also the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null", source: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=2133963443499762&id=100006583811750&_rdr (1)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue and i am pasting complete code here:

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            //query_string = "" + url;
            // view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)
        {
            //  query_string=""+url;

            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function prepareVideo() " +
                    "{ "
                    + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                    +"var ID;"
                    +"var SRC;"
                    + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                    + "{"
                    + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                    + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1)" +
                    "{"
                    + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                    + "console.log(i);"
                    + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                    +"ID=jsonData['videoID'];"
                    +"SRC=jsonData['src'];"

                  //  +"document.getElementsByTagName(\"'+jsonData['videoID']+'\")[0].play();"
                 + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick','FBDownloader.processVideo(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\",\"'+jsonData['videoID']+'\");');"

                    + "}"
                    + "}"

                    + "})()");

        }
    });
```

JAVA ACTIVITY FUNCTION WHICH IS CALL FROM JAVASCRIPT WEBVIEW

```
 public void processVideo(final String vidData, final String vidID)
{

    this.vidData=vidData;
    this.vidID=vidID;
    Get_Download_Permission();

    showtoast("video ID ="+this.vidID);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id="+this.vidID);//193766537709747/");

}
```

Comment: for some video its working but not for all...i'm getting error...and also it opening the video on different page..i can't go back ...can you please tell me about this too